# IBM Worklight - WL.App.getDeviceLanguage() API method does not return correct language code in iOS

Tags: ios, localization, ibm-mobilefirst

In iOS, despite changing the language settings WL.App.getDeviceLanguage() always returns `en`.
Tested on iPhone 5, iPad 4 and several emulators.

If use navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage could detect language correctly in iOS. But the application seems not know it is under other language such as French so application name local string is still in English even other language is available.

Comment: if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 2):

When using iOS, the relevant setting is that of Region Format.

---

1. Created a new Worklight project and application with the iPhone and Android environments
2. Added in `wlCommonInit()`: `alert(WL.App.getDeviceLanguage());`
3. Build All and Deploy, launch in device

**In iOS**
There are two settings related to language:

1. `Settings.app >> General >> International >> Region Format`

   I currently have `Hebrew (Israel)` selected.
   Launching the app shows me an alert with `he`.

   Changing to `Gusii (Kenya)` and re-launching the app then shows me `gu`, and so on for other region formats.
2. `Settings.app >> General >> International >> Language`

   Changes done here will take no effect.

**In Android**
There is only one setting related to language:

1. `Settings >> Language and input`

   I currently have `עברית` (Hebrew) selected.
   Launching the app shows me an alert with `iw`.

   Changing to `English (United States)` and re-launching the app then shows me `en`, and so on for other languages.