# Add dynamic title for Worklight tab bar item

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using worklight tab bar in my hybrid app,I am getting tab bar displayed in html page,i need to apply translation for tab bar title,is it possible to give dynamic value for tab bar item title.can anyone help me in solving this...

Comment: if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In the use case of translation you would need to check for the device locale/language using API methods such as `WL.App.getDeviceLocale` or `WL.App.getDeviceLanguage` when the application launches and before you display the tabbar; based on the language check response, load the appropriate labels for the desired language.

See related question: [IBM Worklight - WL.App.getDeviceLanguage() API method does not return correct language code in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764511/ibm-worklight-wl-app-getdevicelanguage-api-method-does-not-return-correct-la)

---

**Example**
The below was tested in iOS, but should be applicable for Android as well.
See the related question I linked to above.

In common\main.js:

```
var myLabel1, myLabel2;

function wlCommonInit(){
if (WL.App.getDeviceLanguage() == "en") {
        /* Using English */
        myLabel1 = "tab 1";
        myLabel2 = "tab 2";
    }

    if  (WL.App.getDeviceLanguage() == "he") {
    /* Using Hebrew */
        myLabel1 = "טאב 1";
        myLabel2 = "טאב 2";
    }

    WL.TabBar.init();
    WL.TabBar.setVisible(true);
    WL.TabBar.addItem("tabOne", function() {}, myLabel1, {image:"images/myimage.png"});
    WL.TabBar.addItem("tabTwo", function() {}, myLabel2, {image:"images/myimage.png"});    
}
```

In this image you can see the lables in Hebrew, because my device's region is in Hebrew.

[image]