# How to get the current device language for all platforms(iPhone,Windows,Android & Blackberry)

Tags: mobile, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, locale, hybrid-mobile-app

We are developing **hybrid application** using **MobileFirst platform**  with 'dojo'.

My application is available in english and Turkiss.

When selected En or Tr : I want my application to detect the Device language for IOS,Android,Windows & Blackberry devices  and get the default language.

Say **my device default language is in Turkish**,

1. I have launched the application.
2. Selected English as my preference in language selection page of my application.

So now I want all the pages, keyboard pop up, text entered, labels to be changed to english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: [IBM Worklight - WL.App.getDeviceLanguage() API method does not return correct language code in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764511/ibm-worklight-wl-app-getdevicelanguage-api-method-does-not-return-correct-la)

As well as the following Translation tutorial for MobileFirst Platform Foundation: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-client-side-development/enabling-translation/

Comment: Once again thanks Adar, My device language is Turkish,but my app supports both English and Turkish so when I select English in my app inputs and labels should come in English but it is coming in Turkish.I am using single page only for both language.Please help me in this problem

Comment: The API returns the device's  language setting.In your application, if the labels change based on this API , then what you observe is expected. Your logic should take care of handling settings with the application.
You can follow instructions in the tutorial Idan posted or make use of the internationalization feature of dojo